# moving objects and shapes in front or behind another object

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to move the a shape in front of another shape but it is not allowing me. The shapes are not grouped to anything. they are all individual. I would like to know what could be preventing them from not moving in front of another. I know how to do it, its just not letting me.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the shape and try `CTRL-SHIFT-]` to "Bring to Front".  `CTRL-]` will "Bring it Forward" one step at a time.

Also, make sure the object is on a layer above the objects you're trying to bring it in front of.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself and finally figured out how to fix this... select the two objects you want to alter the arrangement for and group them together. Once they are grouped you can bring one of the objects to the 'front' and properly layer them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of things that can cause this. Likely it is one of these two.

Locked Items - Can you select both items? If not then they are locked and can't be moved. Use the Layers palette to unlock any items that you want to move.

Different Layers - Are they on the same layer? Layers supersede individual item ordering. If two items are on different layers, then the item in the bottom layer can't be moved above the current one in that configuration. You can rearrange the layers, or put them on the same layer and rearrange from there, or create a new layer and put one of the items on that layer so it is above/below everything else.

Answer (score 0):

To bring your shape and logo to front on Mac
click <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If the object you are trying to arrange is grouped with other objects it will not work. Select all objects in that layer. Go to Object, click Ungroup and than with your white arrow select the one shape (object) you are trying to arrange to back or front. It should work now.